# Cookie not being sent to AWS ECS server from ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, axios

I am current deploying a MERN Stack application and have successfully deployed the backend api to http://44.198.159.229/. I am now trying to connect it to my client server which is still running on localhost:3000. However, I am running into a cookie related issue. I am receiving the cookie on my frontend from the backend express server, but upon making a get request an authenticated route the frontend is not sending the cookie back. In the network tag in google chrome I see that the cookie is instead filtered out. I have done countless research and browsed various posts but cannot seem to find the solution for this. It works when I check the api route manually in my browser but does not upon sending an axios request. It also works when I'm deploying the backend on my local server but I imagine because they are both on the same domain.

Here is my express configuration on the backend.

```
const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

// Express backend for web application
const app = express();

app.set("trust proxy", true);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Middleware //////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
    session({
        secret: "somethingsecretgoeshere",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: false,
            secure: false,
            maxAge: 10 * 60 * 100000,
            sameSite: 'none'
        },
    })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passportConfig(passport);

app.use("/api", auth_routes);
app.use("/api", major_requirement_routes);
app.use("/api", user_course_routes);


export default app;
```

Here is the route at which I am making the get request to see if a user is authenticated

```
router.get("/auth/check", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user)
    console.log(req.cookies)
    if (req.user) {
        User.findOne({netId: req.user}, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    auth: true,
                    user: req.user,
                    courseList: docs.courseList,
                    semesterList: docs.semesterList,
                    major: docs.major,
                    creditsApplied: docs.creditsApplied,
                    emailAddress: docs.emailAddress,
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.json({auth: false, id: null});
    }
});
```

Here is my axios config

```
import axios from "axios";



const backend_url = "http://44.198.159.229:5000/api"

// const backend_url = "http://localhost:5000/api"

export default axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: backend_url,

});
```

Here is my axios get request on the frontend

```
axios
            .get("auth/check", { withCredentials: true,credentials: 'include',
            })
            .then(({ data}) => {
                console.log(data)
                if (data.auth) {
                    setIsAuthenticated(true);
                    setUser(data.user);
                    setCourseList(data.courseList);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                } else {
                    setIsAuthenticated(false);
                    setCourseList(undefined);
                    setUser(undefined);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }
            })
            .catch(() =>
                console.log(
                    "Something went wrong while trying to fetch your auth status."
                )
            );
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after a lot of research and playing around for a few days I have found a solution. I had to use a SSL and redirect traffic to an https server via AWS load balancing and set sameSite: None httpOnly: true, secure: true. I hope this helps someone else. This is because cookies can only be sent to cross origin sites that are secure. I also had to change my local host to run on https instead of http